# DNS Resolution doesn't work after uninstalling Cisco VPN & Deterministic Network Enhancer in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, dns

I just upgraded my home PC to Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit. After trying various methods to get the Cisco VPN client to work, I gave up and decided to just run it in XP mode. The last steps I tried were in this article ( http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/d880dfe5-7f44-4955-8620-2a9355d8ea8b/ )

After that, I uninstalled the Cisco client and rebooted. I uninstalled the Deterministic Network Enhancer and rebooted again. Both uninstalled successfully, but now I'm not able to resolve any DNS.

The only way I can resolve DNS is to reinstall the DNE, reboot, and uninstall the DNE. Then I am able to resolve DNS lookups until I reboot again. Once it's rebooted, no more DNS.

Any ideas?

Edit: I completely forgot I'd asked this question until harrymc posted his answer. I've since found out that to fix this problem, I need to disable my Local Area Connection and re-enable it. Once I do that I have no trouble making network connections until the next time I reboot at which point I repeat the process. It's annoying, but manageable since I reboot very infrequently.

Answer (score 0):

try setting a static IP on your computer with the appropriate DNS server to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the procedure outlined in [Repair & Reset Winsock in Windows 7](http://windows7themes.net/repair-reset-winsock-windows-7.html) which recommends:

- run a `chkdsk /f /r` to make sure you don’t have any disk erros
- run [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) to validate your system files
- install latest network drivers

Then use a command prompt run as Administrator and enter :

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log
```

See also [reset Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357) that provides a fix-me .exe file.